# Complicated algebraic roots

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, roots, symmetric-polynomials, cubics

I'm working on a problem:

> Suppose that the roots of $$3x^3 +18x^2 +9x -2 = 0$$ are $a$, $b$ and $c$; and the roots of $$x^3 +rx^2 +sx +t = 0$$ are $a+b$, $a+c$ and $b+c$. Determine the cubic equation having a roots of $r$, $s$ and $t$.

My answer is $$x^3 -59x^2 + 876x - 3744.$$ Is my answer wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your answer is wrong because $$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}(a+b)=2(a+b+c)=-12.$$
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}(a+b)(a+c)=(a+b+c)^2+ab+ac+bc=36+3=39$$ and
$$\prod_{\mathrm{cyc}}(a+b)=(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)-abc=-6\cdot3-\frac{2}{3}=-\frac{56}{3}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: My computed r = 12, s = 39 and t = 8,, how will I get -54/3? May ask what is cyc?

Comment: @rosa I wrote it. See please my solution.

Comment: I got $3x^2-209x^2+4260x-26208=0.$

Comment: I finally get your point i got some mistake...What topic in mathematics can I study the multiplication table with cyc?

Comment: You can ask me. I am ready to help. It's a language only. $\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)=(a+b)(b+c)(c+a).$

Comment: Ah?? Cycle... cute language tnx sir for your help :) a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use transformation of equation

As $a+b+c=-\dfrac{18}3,$

let $y=b+c=-6-a\iff a=-6-y$

As $a$ is a root of the given first equation, replace $x$ with $6-y$ and simplify to form a cubic equation in $y$

We can easily discern that $a+b,c+a$ are the rest two roots

Compare it with the given second equation to find the values of $r,s,t$

Can you take it home from here?